# Place background image in 45deg rotated div

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to create something like below image.

[image]

With the image horizontal but the div it's placed in rotated. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Also, linking to images is not accepted, please insert image in question.

Comment: @Lafexlos sorry, please disregard my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Sure is! This will work fine in IE9+, along with all other modern browsers.

Big credit to [Craig Buckler's doc on applying CSS3 transformations to background images](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/)

```css
#myelement {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#myelement:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/any') 0 0 repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="myelement"></div>
```

Comment: what if he have to set the image dinamically? `before` and `after` pseudoelements can't be "directly" changed. Your approach is right but I think @Jinu Kurian 's answer is better

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. Try this out

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pic {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -25px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="pic">

  </div>
</div>
```